# R: how to open a running r script in rstudio

Tags: r, session, rstudio, gnu-screen

I've been running an analysis in a computer cluster that works on linux from my computer, and I run it on rstudio. This analysis takes like 12 days, so before running the r script I made a "screen" to save the ssh session, just in case.

The thing is that, after 6 days of running, someone switched off my computer so rstudio was closed, but  when I look on the computer cluster, the script stills running (looking in htop  the "Command" name is "/usr/lib/rstudio/bin/rsession --config-file none --program-mode desktop --www-port 10173").

Does anybody know if it's possible, and if so, how to open that rstudio session again?

Comment: Are you using RStudio Server? Then this shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: no... I'm using Rstudio Version 0.98.507 – © 2009-2013 RStudio, Inc.

Comment: Well, that's a mistake. You might be out of luck then. I've voted for migration to superuser since this is not really a programming question.